# Clausius-Clapeyron equation and coexistence curve for Bose-Einstein Condensate

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, bose-einstein-condensate

I am tasked with "deriving" the Clausius-Clapeyron Equation for the ideal Bose-Einstein condensate and plotting the coexistence curve. Yet, I am unsure how would I accomplish this task. Can I just use the regular CC equation

$$
\frac{dP}{dT} = \frac{L}{T \Delta v}
$$

or should I re-derive it keeping in mind BEC properties. I legitimately have no idea how to attack this question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain the P-T curve of phase transition? If so, since you can simply get critical temperature as a function of particle density $n$, then I guess you could just replace the $n$ with with pressure $P$ by considering BE statistics.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~sint/ReadingWeek-February-2012_sols_q5.pdf